# What user research data is available on Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: usability, users, research, bootstrap, twitter

Has anyone come across any user research or done studies that can show improvement in usability and user experience using the Twitter Bootstrap framework?

I would especially be interested in the real usability of the rich ui components as well as the overall experience of these rich interactions.

> Based on question asked in the comments below:
>
> "What is it about Bootstrap itself that would be part of a usability study?"

I am specifically referring to the ui components of bootstrap versus normal html ui components.

Comment: Would be very interested to see this as well—for a well used system I've seen little to show why it makes the choices it does around UI elements.

Comment: What is it about Bootstrap itself that would be part of a usability study? If you look at some [examples of sites that are built on Bootstrap](http://expo.getbootstrap.com/), you can see that they are all very different. Are you interested specifically in the usability of Bootstrap's default styling?

Comment: Bootstrap is simply an HTML/CSS framework, in and of itself it provides no "usability and user experience" since it's up to Bootstrap users to actually USE the framework to create, what is hopefully, a good user experience. As Matt said above, bootstrap sites are all very different. Most sites that use boostrap these days use them just for the responsive grid anyways since the bootstrap UI is so overused these days in web design.

Comment: @MattObee as stated: specifically the ui components in bootstrap versus using normal html components.

Comment: What do you define as "normal HTML components"? UI components in bootstrap are HTML componens with some styling over them.

Comment: Given the comments, which I agree with I vote that we close this as it will be too broad and no clear answer will be objective.

Answer (score 2):

The "normal" HTML components appear differently from browser to browser, so if anything, Bootstrap would make a multi-devise user more comfortable than stock elements.

Moreover, testing the individual UI elements of the framework would be rather pointless, since trying to grade individual elements outside of the larger context of what the screen - or the site as a whole - is trying to accomplish is a useless act. "Terrible" elements can be made quite usable, and "great" elements can be made completely unusable, depending on the talent of who is using them.

Let me put it another way: Take two cameras - a $50 point-and-shoot, and a $1000 DSLR. I can guarantee that a pro photographer will still be able to take better pictures with the point-and-shoot than an amateur with the DSLR, because it isn't the tools that matter as much as how they are used.